# Eclipse - bin Folder keeps creating itself

Tags: windows, eclipse

This is a long one, but *please*, bear with me. I really need help here.

I use Eclipse (latest version) to play with some programs of my own. During installation (?), it asked me where I'd like to put in my Workspace folder. I  set it to default, but, not wanting to dig through Documents and such (I have my own Documents folder on another drive), I made sure that every project I have is condensed into one "Projects" folder, not in the Workspace. My "Projects" folder contains every program I've coded so far, from C# to Java, as well as the necessary tools, like the Eclipse folder.

It worked fine for me, until I decided I want to do another project. So, I navigated to my "Projects" folder, and then created it there.

Now for some reason, Eclipse treated the directory I navigated to as my project folder. As in, new folders like bin, src, etc. started popping up in my otherwise organized folder. Visual Studio does not have this problem, and actually creates a *new* folder for your project under whatever directory you set it to.

So I, in a 'Monday blues' move, went into Eclipse and deleted my project. Eclipse wasted no time in deleting my entire "Projects" folder and everything in it - including itself, apparently. **Gah**.

I quickly closed Eclipse, but it kept saying something about 'Saving Workspace' which I assumed meant "*Don't close me yet, I'm still deleting your files.*"

I thought I was being sensible when I terminated it via the Task Manager. It stopped deleting my stuff, but out of the dozen or so programs, I only managed to save three.

Wanting to start over again, I deleted (what's left of) my Eclipse, so I can 'install' it again, and let it have its way of where to create projects and save my files, so that this doesn't happen again. Unfortunately, one folder keeps returning no matter how many times I delete it. The aforementioned **bin** folder, a name that needs at least two adjectives and the suffix "Of the Damned."

So, to summarize:

- I lost majority of my programs.
- I lost my Eclipse.
- And folder 'Bin' keeps popping up.

And so I'd like to ask:

- Can I recover my files?
- How can I setup Eclipse so that it creates a new project folder when I create a new project instead of treating the directory as the project folder?
- How can I permanently get rid of that haunted Bin folder?

If anyone an help out here, thank you so much. This has easily been one of my worst Mondays.

As of now, I have tried:

- Restarting my PC (didn't work, Bin Folder is still there)
- Downloading and running a new copy of Eclipse (didn't work either)

Comment: Sorry I haven't read all your question because it is too long. But you need the bin folder as it contains the compiled classes but you could change the location in the project properties.

Comment: I don't need the Bin folder anymore as I have no more Java programs, and neither do I have Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I have struggles also on my Eclipse for the past few weeks. I answer each of your question below, hope that helps.

`Can I recover my files?` - If your programs are not physically removed from disk, you can add it back when you have your Eclipse running

`How can I setup Eclipse so that it creates a new project folder when I create a new project instead of treating the directory as the project folder?` - Create your project by clicking File->New->Android Application Project (if android). Then input the application name,etc. Click Next and uncheck create project in workspace, from there you can have your own location or directory of your project.

How can I permanently get rid of that haunted Bin folder?  - In may case, I downloaded a fresh copy of Eclipse. I used the adt bundle which can be downloaded here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: They are physically removed from the disk. I'm beginning to think this is hopeless to recover them. But thanks for the answer, anyway. I've downloaded another copy of Eclipse - here's hoping it works.

Comment: @zack_falcon I think Bin folder is normal if we create a project, did you mean it creates a lot of duplicates?

Comment: No, I meant after I got rid of everything, my projects and Eclipse itself, a folder named 'Bin' keeps creating itself in my now-barren 'Projects' folder.

Answer (score -1):

the sad news is, that Eclipse does not just delete the projects into the bin, like it would happen with the "delete" by clicking on the folder and manually deleting it. You could try with recovery software, but it is not an assurance it will work, or recover all your lost data.
For the more of it, in the Bin folder that is made automatically in any Java project, you get compiled classes which are what gets packaged/archived into any jars that are created.(I hope this makes sense, I couldn't find a better way to explain myself.)

For the set-up of Eclipse I would have a look at the page of Eclipse, maybe a forum, or a FAQ is there. 
I for instance use Netbeans, which does from the start always create a new folder for the new projects.
I hope I could somehow help!
Here a little link to a recovery software that has a good reputation: http://www.piriform.com/recuva

Kind regards,
Dom
Extra edit: Version Control is an awesome tool to save your buttex from trouble like this ;)